# Accessing the Address Book in iPhone OS

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, addressbook, article

I'm wondering if someone could direct me to an article that explains how to access the address book contacts in the form that Address Book on the desktop can read.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

In the stanford uni lectures on iPhone development there is a lecture dedicated
to using the address book. These can be accessed via iTunes.

Hope this helps.
Rgds.,
J.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a thread I saw on MacRumors that looks promising:

[Accessing Address Book in iPhone SDK?](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-449981.html)

Answer (score 1):

Apple now has an official guide as part of the iOS Reference Library:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [small how-to](http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2009/01/21/cocoa-touch-tutorial-extract-address-book-address-values-on-iphone-os/) many moons ago.